# Why am i get this error "Error interpreting JPEG image file (Not a JPEG file: starts with 0x9e 0xdc)"

Tags: image, jpeg

Why am i get this message

> "Error interpreting JPEG image file (Not a JPEG file: starts with 0x9e
>   0xdc)"

when i try to open image?

Comment: What sort of file is it really? The message says that it is *not* a JPG, even though it may have that extension.

Comment: I try in terminal : file img.JPG. get this result img.JPG :data

Answer (score 0):

If it does not start with FFD8, it is not a valid JPEG stream.